# Facebook like emoticon option onLongpress of a button

Tags: android

How to get Facebook like emoticons, on long press of a button? I want to show the exact replica of the same Facebook feature.

Comment: Facebook uses pop library for it's animation

Comment: I wish I had FB code to share with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the library like facebook react button [FBReaction](https://github.com/dbof10/FBReaction?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5490) cheers